# How to set specific view in emberJS with itemcontroller

Tags: ember.js

I have the following code:

```
{{#each categories.items itemController="item"}}
```

When I open the Ember inspector, it shows the view to be "virtual". I want to set the view to be "item" so that it follows the ember view I set out called itemView. I know we can set an itemController: is it possible to set an item view?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible using the optional 'itemViewClass' parameter.

```
{{#each categories.items itemController="item" itemViewClass="otherView"}}
```

Though I would recommend discontinuing using that and itemController as the latest Best Practice is to use a component within the each block.

So for your example:

```
// Ember 1.10+

{{#each categories.items as |item|}}
  {{some-component item=item}}
{{/each}}

// Ember 1.9-

{{#each item in categories.items}}
  {{some-component item=item}}
{{/each}}
```

Then you put your logic needed in the component object instead of the item controller.